# Inserta el mismo valor en un array javascript con push

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy conformando un objeto dentro de un ciclo **for** para despues insertarlo en un **array**. El objeto se me esta conformando sin problema, el detalle lo tengo a la hora que inserto los datos en el array, ya que a la hora de insertar el ultimo registro me cambia los anteriores y me coloca el ultimo en todos los **item**. A continuación les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

**Mi código:**

```
    let arrayval = _data.valdatos.split("~");
    var datagrapharray = []; 
    var datagraphobj = new Object();
    for(i=0; i < arrayval.length; i++){
        linegrafph = arrayval[i].split("#");
        datagraphobj["label"] =  linegrafph[1];
        datagraphobj["backgroundColor"] = linegrafph[2];
        datagraphobj["borderColor"] = linegrafph[3];
        datagraphobj["borderWidth"] = 1;
        datagraphobj["data"] = linegrafph[0].split(",");
        console.log(datagraphobj);
        datagrapharray.push(datagraphobj);
    }   
    console.log(datagrapharray);
```

**Mis objetos:**

```
{label: "Objeto1", backgroundColor: " rgba(255,0,0,0.2)", borderColor: " rgba(255,0,0,1)", borderWidth: 1, data: Array(12)}
{label: "Objeto2", backgroundColor: " rgba(0,64,128,0.2)", borderColor: " rgba(0,64,128,1)", borderWidth: 1, data: Array(12)}
{label: "Objeto3", backgroundColor: " rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", borderColor: " rgba(0,0,0,1)", borderWidth: 1, data: Array(12)}
```

**Mi Array:**

```
0: {label: "Objeto3", backgroundColor: " rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", borderColor: " rgba(0,0,0,1)", borderWidth: 1, data: Array(12), …}
1: {label: "Objeto3", backgroundColor: " rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", borderColor: " rgba(0,0,0,1)", borderWidth: 1, data: Array(12), …}
2: {label: "Objeto3", backgroundColor: " rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", borderColor: " rgba(0,0,0,1)", borderWidth: 1, data: Array(12), …}
```

Comment: puede colocar el resultado deseado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se soluciona *limpiando el objeto* antes de volver a insertar los valores ya que actualmente no lo estas haciendo, por eso te pisa cada valor:

```js
const data = [
  { value: 1, name: 'Uno' },
  { value: 2, name: 'Dos' },
  { value: 3, name: 'Tres' },
  { value: 4, name: 'Cuatro' }
]

let nuevoArreglo = [];
let dataObject = new Object();

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  dataObject = {};
  dataObject['value'] = data[i].value;
  dataObject['name'] = data[i].name;
  nuevoArreglo.push(dataObject);
}
console.log(nuevoArreglo);
```

Nos comentas como te va colega =)

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me quedo